# What's the minimum patch level required when migrating SP2010 -> SP2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, migration, upgrade

I can't find any documentation or blog posts for SP2010 -> SP2013 migration. What is the minimum patch level of the SP2010 farm when upgrading to SP2013? E.g. SP1, SP2, ..?

Comment: SP1 is enough i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP2010 needs to be patched to at least SP1, or Workflows and a possibly configured remote BLOB might face issues. Other than that, I haven't come across any mentioned patch requirement. However, while lacking an official "no, that's all"-answer, you should rely on the best upgrade practices throughout the process, as it should include several steps which verify the readiness to upgrade of each object.

Just to give an idea of how broad the upgrade process is, there's e.g. [this 6-part blog post series](http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-To-Planning-for-Upgrading-from-SharePoint-2010-to-SharePoint-2013) which includes detail-level steps.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum SP1 for 2010 is recommended for workflows to work properly after the Upgrade. Also run psconfig for SP fixes after upgrade.

Comment: Refer this:
http://www.spdockit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/SPDocKit-Best-Practice-Reports.pdf

Page 5 "Upgrade Ready"